# Sorting database results by double column in PHP

Tags: php, database, sorting

I retrieve some data from a MySQL database which represents a location. It includes the latitude and longitude of the location.

On the client I use HTML geolocation to get the user's latitude and longitude. These values are submitted to the PHP script which retrieves the data in the form of a hidden form field.

I can calculate the distance from the user's location to the location retrieved from the database.

I need to sort the data returned by the distance. I have tried this code

```
// First I loop over the results
foreach($data as $venue)
{
    $venue['distance'] = calculateDistance(users_lat, users_long, 
                                           $venue['lat'], $venue['long']);
}
```

Then I try and use array_multisort to sort by distance column

```
array_multisort($data['distance'], SORT_ASC, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

I get this warning:

```
Warning: array_multisort(): Argument #1 is expected to be an array or a sort flag
```

var dump (first 3 results)

```
["Distance"]=> float(1.5)
["Distance"]=> float(2)
["Distance"]=> float(1.7)
```

I am still getting the warning though.

Comment: can you `var_dump on $data` and show us the results?

Comment: var_dump shows distance as blank so I presume $data is not updated

Comment: that's it!! that the reason your `array_multisort()` isn't working

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is with your data inside $data not the loop:

```
$aData[ 'distance' ][] = 2344234;
$aData[ 'distance' ][] = 54345;
$aData[ 'distance' ][] = 364646;
$aData[ 'distance' ][] = 5477474457;
$aData[ 'distance' ][] = 34;
$aData[ 'distance' ][] = 1;
$aData[ 'distance' ][] = 34556;

var_dump( $aData );
array_multisort( $aData['distance'], SORT_ASC, SORT_NUMERIC );

var_dump( $aData );
```

Comment: The results of calculateDistance will return doubles, will this still work?

Comment: Appears to work when I cast the values as ( double ) $aData[ 'distance' ][] = ( double ) 2344234; I'd add some checks for if( !empty( $aData ) ) { ...

Answer (score 0):

You are over ridding the values of `$venu` try thus; 
$result = array();

```
foreach($data as $venue)
{
    $result['distance'][] = calculateDistance(users_lat, users_long, 
                                           $venue['lat'], $venue['long']);
}
```

then:

```
array_multisort($result['distance'][], SORT_ASC, SORT_NUMERIC);
```